# python subprocess fails to find shell commands when started by systemctl

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, systemd, systemctl

When I launch a python application with systemctl, python subprocess fails when running standard shell commands such as tail, awk, etc.

Code example:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['awk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

save the above and run it via python app.py - no problems.

Run that same command using systemctl and you will get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'awk': 'awk'
```

The same goes for all other commands that I know for a fact that I have installed - such as tail, sed, etc.

I tried different ways of starting a subprocess such as `subprocess.run()`, `subprocess.call()`. I also tries using the `shell=True` and even the `executable='/bin/bash` argument.

For the systemctl side, I tried running locally using `systemctl start service_name --user` and various combinations of the config - such as changing the process Type, running as root, different User, and Group.

Here is an example of the config:

```
[Unit]
Description={{ project_name }} Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User={{ user }}
Group={{ user_group }}

Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

WorkingDirectory=/home/{{ user }}/{{ project_folder }}
ExecStart=/home/{{ user }}/{{ project_folder }}/virtualenv/bin/python start.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: `tail` is already executable; why are you trying to use `bash`?

Comment: Please provide the content of your `systemd` service in question

Comment: tail isn't executable in the subprocess when running with systemd that's why I tried that.

Comment: I'll add the systemd service shortly but it's quite standard.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to `tail`?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out, that the python subprocess is using the PATH environment variables for the location of the executables.

When running systemctl, these are not provided.

I found this by comparing print(os.environ) when running with systemctl and when running with python app.py.

Add this line in the [Service] section of the systemctl config file:

```
Environment="PATH=/home/{{ user }}/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
```

Comment: That's what *everything* uses to find executables.

Comment: You should also include `/bin`

Comment: @tripleee yea I know. I was extremely surprised to find that systemctl does not provide these.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description={{ project_name }} Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User={{ user }}
Group={{ user_group }}

Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

Environment="PATH=/usr/bin"
WorkingDirectory=/home/{{ user }}/{{ project_folder }}
ExecStart=/home/{{ user }}/{{ project_folder }}/virtualenv/bin/python start.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This specifies the environment directory where the program executes the awk command.

In ubuntu 20.04 LTS, modify the code as follows:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/awk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```